# VS Code keyboard shortcut not working

Tags: visual-studio-code

Installed VSCode and same as usual I'm used to use the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to open the command palette. However, it does not seem to work. Checking the keyboard shortcuts the default is actually that key:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and was able to resolve it by right-clicking on the Shortcut → 'Change When Expression' → updating it to `editorTextFocus`.

This is what my working Shortcut looks like

[image: screenshot]